Why did Doctor Baxter ask a rhetorical question here?
In Poor Things (2023), Doctor Baxter, who has a deformed face, is describing
his experiment called Bella to his student, Max:

Max: Who was she?
Doctor: No idea. But would you rather the world did not have Bella?

Why did Doctor Baxter ask a rhetorical question here?

Do you mean to ask why the question was asked (which can be trivially answered "because the character wanted to") or what it means?

A lot of this revolves around the science fiction portion of the movie. Minor spoilers ahead.
Bella is the main character. But Bella was previously a dead woman. To save the body, Doctor Baxter transplants the brain of the woman's unborn infant into her.
Max is asking Doctor Baxter who the woman was before she died. Baxter does not know, but his question to Max is to note that the woman was dead either way. He's trying to get him to see the good that is Bella, and not dwell on the dead woman's identity.
